# Ubuntu can't find rails as a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

i am using ubuntu 12.04. I've installed rails with rvm. i added required lines to .bashrc and .bash_profile. however when i want to run rails terminal says:

`The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails`

i could run rails in my few attemps, but i used a different approach:

1. open a new terminal
2. logged as root `sudo su`
3. re-login my user account, `login user`

and it worked few times.

Comment: Have you set defaults for `RVM` and created gemset ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had same problem, on my command line I fixed it by doing this

```
/bin/bash --login
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

make sure:

```
rvm use ruby
```

works, follow all instructions displayed to you.